# not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers when using JSON headers

Tags: apache, angular

Trying to send a post request to my Laravel API from the angular 2 app.

My method:

```
getCombinas(test)
   {
       this.loadedResult = false;
       let body = JSON.stringify({
                test: test,
        });
    this.http.request('testAPI', { body:body, method:'POST' })
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
   }
```

In my httpd.conf (apache configuration) I allowed cors:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

And I'm using custom request options class in my angular 2 app:

```
import {BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers} from '@angular/http';

export class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

     merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
    options.url = 'MY_API_URL/api/' + options.url;
    if (options.method === 1) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    options.headers = headers;
         }
    return super.merge(options);
  }

}
```

The error occured only after I added those 2 lines:

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

But without them, My Laravel get text/plain response and I can't use it.. I need JSON response.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If missing you have to enable apache mod_header with command

```
a2enmod headers
```

then restart apache

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should additionally write **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** header with necessary value to response.